# What kind of ounces do Migos mean?

Tags: lyrics

I am talking about the song Migos - Ounces.

> All I ever wanted was to get rid of them ounces

I know gold ounces. But why does he want to get rid of them?

I'm from Europe maybe this question is stupid? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ounces" is a reference to quantities of drugs. Once of the main themes of the song is earning money through drug dealing, so "get[ting] rid of them ounces" means selling drugs.